# Mailchimp variant limit?

Tags: html, mailchimp

Iv created a mailchimp template, just like any other, having done so many times before. We use mc:variant to create different sections for the admin team to create the emails in any way they need. This particular template is the most complex we have built, with 9 different varient blocks. For some reason one of the blocks does not work as expected. If you select the footer block, it shows the full width block. If you select the full width block, it also shows the full width block. The varient names are set up correctly so I cannot see any reason for this. Has anyone experienced this before?

I can provide code on request.

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered the answer. The variant that was getting confused had an mc:edit inside which did not have a unique name. So when you added this variant it was using the content from the other varient with the same mc:edit name.